# opencart 2.0.3.1 quantity plus minus NaN error

Tags: javascript, opencart2.x

I have a opencart 2.0.3.1 store and got coding added from a opencart extension but am getting NaN error when click on the plus button

a link to jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/b9L6tmq1/. I had to add code as would not let me post without code and there is a lot of javascript code

```
<?php if ($product['minimum']) { ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="input-quantity"><?php echo $entry_qty; ?></label>
                        <i class="fa fa-minus minus-qty"></i>
                          <input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>" size="2" class="control" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="qtymin" value="<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>"/>
                        <i class="fa fa-plus plus-qty"></i>
                  </div>
                <?php } ?>

        <div class="centerproductbuttons">
            <button type="button" onclick="cartqty = plusminus.sel(this); if(cartqty != false){cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>',cartqty);}" class="rounded" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
            <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>" class="roundedeye" data-toggle="tooltip" title="View Product"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </div>
```

Updated Code: I updated one line to the following to have a default value so now it shows 1 in the input field and changed it back to text type input field and it's sort of working now

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" class="control" />
```

Only issue now is the minus button when clicked still says the message Quantity Must Be This product has a minimum quantity of 1. Is that because of the following line or the javascript coding?

```
<input type="hidden" name="qtymin" value="<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>"/>
```

Comment: You can change the input type from `text` into `number` - this way you will pass numbers to the function.

Comment: I altered it that way and got the up/down on the input as it's now a number but would like to use the plus/minus buttons but they only work when there is a number in the input field. Also found the minus button appears with the message when click on to try and reduce the number in the input field "Quantity Must Be This product has a minimum quantity of 1"

Comment: `<input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>" size="2" class="control" />` doesn't show value?

Comment: No does not show a value in the input field, it's blank but if look at the source code it shows This product has a minimum quantity of 1

Comment: I have amended my original post with updated code as getting bit closer to it working apart from the minus button issue now which is mentioned in the updated original post

Comment: Sorry just sorted it I think, I changed the second input tag that mentioned in my updated code to 1 in the value and the minus button is not getting the message now